# Time comparison between colums with datatype varchar and date

Tags: sql, oracle, types, date-conversion

In my table, I have 2 columns i.e. `RECEIVED_TIME` & `PROCESSES_DATE`.

- `RECEIVED_TIME` is a varchar column which contains time in `HH24MI` format e.g. 1430 for 2:30 pm.
- `PROCESSED_DATE` is date column which contains full date in `DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS` format e.g. 23-MAY-2018 16:10:00 for 23rd May 18, 4.10 PM.

Now I want to find out those rows for which processed date is beyond 30 mins compared to received time.

Pls help me out with query.

Comment: Did you try anything so far ?

Comment: As a hint, use TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'hh24mi') to get the hh24mi part of your date field.

Comment: Bt how do I compare these 2 columns to find out those records which are processed after 30 mins after receiving.

Comment: You have a received TIME, but you don't know the DATE on which the item was received. Therefore, given the data you have, I don't see how the question can be answered with any confidence, unless there are some other rules/assumptions which can be made. Best of luck.

Comment: Please post the `create table ...`  statement (the DDL).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it only makes sense if everything happens the same day. For example:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (received_time  varchar2(20),
  3     processes_date date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values
  2    ('1430', to_date('23.05.2018 16:10:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test values
  2    ('1430', to_date('23.05.2018 18:10:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test values
  2    ('1430', to_date('23.05.2018 14:50:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));

1 row created.

SQL>
```

If we convert the RECEIVED_TIME to DATE datatype, we get this:

```
SQL> select to_date(received_time, 'hh24mi') rectim,
  2         processes_date
  3  from test;

RECTIM           PROCESSES_DATE
---------------- ----------------
01.05.2018 14:30 23.05.2018 16:10
01.05.2018 14:30 23.05.2018 18:10
01.05.2018 14:30 23.05.2018 14:50

SQL>
```

Aha; `RECEIVED_TIME` is "converted" to the first day of the current month. We'll do the same with `PROCESSES_DATE`, using combination of `TO_DATE` and `TO_CHAR` functions with the appropriate format masks:

```
SQL> select to_date(received_time, 'hh24mi') rectim,
  2         to_date(to_char(processes_date, 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') proctim
  3  from test;

RECTIM           PROCTIM
---------------- ----------------
01.05.2018 14:30 01.05.2018 16:10
01.05.2018 14:30 01.05.2018 18:10
01.05.2018 14:30 01.05.2018 14:50

SQL>
```

Nice; now we can do some calculation and see which row took more than 30 minutes to finish; I'm rounding values to 5 decimals to save space. Also, note that I'm doing it step-by-step so that you'd see how we get to *minutes* because the difference of two DATE datatype values is the *number of days* between them:

```
SQL> with inter as
  2    (select to_date(received_time, 'hh24mi') rectim,
  3            to_date(to_char(processes_date, 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') proctim
  4    from test
  5    )
  6  select
  7    proctim,
  8    rectim,
  9    round(proctim - rectim, 5) days,
 10    round((proctim - rectim) * 24, 5) hours,
 11    round((proctim - rectim) * 26 * 60, 5) minutes
 12  from inter;

PROCTIM          RECTIM                 DAYS      HOURS    MINUTES
---------------- ---------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
01.05.2018 16:10 01.05.2018 14:30     ,06944    1,66667  108,33333
01.05.2018 18:10 01.05.2018 14:30     ,15278    3,66667  238,33333
01.05.2018 14:50 01.05.2018 14:30     ,01389     ,33333   21,66667

SQL>
```

Finally, the result you're looking for:

```
SQL> with inter as
  2    (select to_date(received_time, 'hh24mi') rectim,
  3            to_date(to_char(processes_date, 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') proctim
  4    from test
  5    )
  6  select
  7    proctim,
  8    rectim,
  9    round((proctim - rectim) * 26 * 60, 5) minutes
 10  from inter
 11  where (proctim - rectim) * 26 * 60 > 30;

PROCTIM          RECTIM              MINUTES
---------------- ---------------- ----------
01.05.2018 16:10 01.05.2018 14:30  108,33333
01.05.2018 18:10 01.05.2018 14:30  238,33333

SQL>
```